# How to visualize dask graphs?

Tags: python-2.7, graphviz, dask

I am following the [official docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/inspect.html#visualize-graphs-with-dot), however, getting the error during import.

```
F:\>python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36)[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

>>> from dask.dot import dot_graph

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\dot.py", line 11, in <module>
    graphviz = import_required("graphviz", "Drawing dask graphs requires the "
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py", line 70, in import_required
raise RuntimeError(error_msg)
RuntimeError: Drawing dask graphs requires the `graphviz` python library and the `graphviz` system library to be installed.
>>>
```

I am running Anaconda and have installed graphviz.

```
C:\>conda install graphviz
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda:
#
graphviz                  2.38.0                        2
```

I've got a directory `C:\Anaconda\Library\bin\graphviz` with the bunch of .exe, .dll and other files inside. There is also something in `PATH` variable:

```
F:\>where dot
C:\Anaconda\Library\bin\dot.bat
```

Here is the content of that file (C:\Anaconda\Library\bin\dot.bat):

```
@echo off 
%~dp0.\graphviz\dot.exe %*
```

I have dask 0.11.0 installed:

```
F:\>conda list dask
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda:
#
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
dask                      0.11.0                   py27_0
```

These errors appear both in Windows and in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 with all recent updates).

What else does it require?

Comment: What about `where graphviz`?

Comment: "Could not find files for the given pattern(s)". But this command is not supposed to find anything, AFAIK, since GraphViz is the name of the project. Main executable from this package is dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using Anaconda, but generaly if you wish to use `graphviz` you should:

1. Install the graphviz python **module** (probably with `pip install graphviz`).
2. [Download](http://graphviz.org/Download..php) and install the graphviz **software**.

Comment: I know. It was installed in C:\Anaconda\Library\bin\graphviz

Comment: Are you sure that is the software and not the module?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've got another installation of previous version of the GraphViz. Directory contents are pretty similar.

Comment: ImportError: No module named graphviz

Comment: So perhaps it's the opposite problem, you didn't install the `graphviz` module. Try `pip install graphviz`.

Comment: The conda graphviz package is pretty broken.  Installing graphviz traditionally as suggested here is generally a better bet.

Answer (score 1):

To use the visualizing part of dask in anaconda, install both the graphviz and python-graphviz packages. Dask depends on a python interface to graphviz to do visualizations.

```
$ conda install graphviz python-graphviz
```

Comment: yes, as explained in https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/485#issuecomment-279296254  this step is necessary